# How to generate address from xpub in JS?

Tags: javascript, addresses, public-key, bip39

How to generate address from xpub in JS?  Should i use BIP39 or 44? If yes, how exactly?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ethereumjs-wallet](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-walle), from their [unit tests](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet/blob/master/src/test/index.js#L102-L107)

```
var xpub = 'xpub661MyMwAqRbcGout4B6s29b6gGQsowyoiF6UgXBEr7eFCWYfXuZDvRxP9zEh1Kwq3TLqDQMbkbaRpSnoC28oWvjLeshoQz1StZ9YHM1EpcJ'
var addr = Wallet.fromExtendedPublicKey(xpub).getAddressString()
assert(addr, '0xb800bf5435f67c7ee7d83c3a863269969a57c57c')
```